# Paper size in an RDLC report not set correctly

Tags: c#, rdlc

So the problem I have is that even if I set the report size in the report property --> layout setting, the output won't come out as what I expect. I want `Letter` size report, but it always give me `A4` size. I am using VS 2012.

Comment: You need to make sure your printer is not overriding the printing options. Check your printer settings in the OS.

Comment: Hi Alex. Thank you for your prompt feedback. However, the outcome I mean here is not the printed outcome. Rather, when I open the file with Adobe reader and check the page properties, I can see that the page size is A4 (8.26 X 11.69 in).